# Push only the UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-cell

Is there a way to just push the right UITableView into the left one without pushing the whole view?

[image: UITableViews]

I had an idea about just reloading the table with new data and another `CustomCellIdentifier` but I'm sure there is a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instantiate the second table with a frame that places it offscreen to the right (ie with a x coordinate greater than the screen width) and then 'slide' it onscreen by setting the x position to 0 inside an animation block. That would appear to slide in over the top of the first table.

If you wanted the first table to slide away to the left, you'd need to set its x position to a negative value in the same animation block.

(This assumes that you're creating the tables manually and not with `UITableViewControllers`, however.)